# PHP shopping cart showing unselected items

Tags: php, forms, session, shopping-cart

I am trying to do a project that is a shopping cart.  I thought based on the way I set up my forms for the items in the product list that only the ones that had been selected would show up in the cart but instead it shows all three items no matter which one I click.  Can someone tell me what I need to change.

the main page where the products get listed:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Final Project</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$_SESSION['maxItems'] = 2;
?>
<form id="item01" method="post" action="cart.php">
<?php  $_SESSION['cart'][0] = array('name'=>'item01','price'=>'$11');  ?>
<label>Item 01 for sale</label>
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart"  name="item01">
</form>

<br>

<form id="item02" method="post" action="cart.php">
<?php  $_SESSION['cart'][1] = array('name'=>'item02','price'=>'$22');  ?>
<label>Item 02 for sale</label>
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="item02">
</form>

<br>

<form id="item03" method="post" action="cart.php">
<?php  $_SESSION['cart'][2] = array('name'=>'item03','price'=>'$33');  ?>
<label>Item 03 for sale</label>
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="item03">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the php code for my cart page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$max_items = $_SESSION['maxItems'];
for($i=0; $i <= $max_items; $i++){
    $current_name = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['name'];
    $current_price = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['price'];
echo "item is " . $current_name . " " . $current_price . "<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are creating the session in the html, so on page load even if a user didn't submit the form !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, actually, you're not getting the values of which button you clicked, you're just simply setting them as is. You need to processes the form, then, you set them on the session. Second, you really don't need multiple form tags, you only need one. Third, make some initializations, (item list, the session itself, etc.). Just create an array of items. Rough and gun example: (Same Page Form processing)

```
<?php
// initializations
session_start();
$_SESSION['maxItems'] = 2;
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
$item_list = array('item01' => 11, 'item02' => 22, 'item03' => 33);

// add
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $item = $_POST['add'];
    $value = $item_list[$item];
    if(count($_SESSION['cart']) >= $_SESSION['maxItems']) {
        echo 'Your cart is full, sorry.';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('name' => $item, 'price' => $item_list[$item]);
    }
}

// clear all
if(isset($_POST['remove_all'])) { $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PHP Final Project</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Item 01 for sale</label>
        <button type="submit" name="add" value="item01">Add To Cart</button>
        <br/>
        <label>Item 02 for sale</label>
        <button type="submit" name="add"value="item02">Add To Cart</button>
        <br/>
        <label>Item 03 for sale</label>
        <button type="submit" name="add" value="item03">Add To Cart</button>

        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="remove_all" value="Clear Cart" />
    </form>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0): ?>
    <div class="chosen_items">
    <h3>Current Items</h3>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value): ?>
        <p><?php echo "Item: <strong>". $value['name']. "</strong> Price: $".$value['price']; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aan9vB)

Comment: Thanks.  One question.  I noticed there is not action set in the form, how does the form know to use the php in the page for the submit action?  That is the part i am a little unclear on.  how to get the select item in the form and put that info into the session and pass it to the php code to process it.  Thanks.  I plan to accept your answer but wanted to ask this follow up question first in case it doesn't let me ask afterward. Thanks.

Comment: @user3064141 yes that is true, if you leave the `action=""` attribute blank, it is understood that it will be processed on the same page. With regards to the selected items, when you click submit, the variables doesn't go immediately on `$_SESSION`, since the form is using `method="POST"`, the submitted values are inside the `$_POST` first. So the logic is, get the items inside `$_POST` and put them inside `$_SESSION`. From then on, it will carry on to the other pages as long as the session is set.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the $_POST global variable.  I got so focused on using $_SESSION it slipped my mind.  Thanks.